# How to prove that there is a monotone path in a graph with a length of greater or equal to average degree?

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph with M edges, labeled by the numbers 1, 2, . . . , M. A monotone path is a path along which the labels of the edges create a monotone sequence. Show that there exists a monotone path whose length is greater or equal to the average degree.

I've tried different approaches but couldn't prove this.

**Note**: we can't use Ramsey theory.

Comment: This is trivial for average degree $\leq 2$, but it gets harder from there.

Comment: I guess "graph" means "simple graph" and the "length" of a path is the number of edges, right? Is a "path" a walk with no repeated vertices or edges? Why is use of Ramsey theory forbidden, is there some obvious way it would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this result, but with the requirement to find a monotone trail of length
at least the average degree (a trail is allowed to repeat vertices, but not edges, so it is not the same as a path). This is probably what you wanted to ask, but if it isn't, I still share the proof, because it is delightful.

Put a counter at each vertex, all initialized at value 0.

Now add the edges one by one, in sequence of increasing label.

For every edge you put down exchange the counters at the endpoints of the edge
and increase them both by 1.

Note that at every moment the counter value indicates how far the counter has travelled. Also note that counters only travel along an increasing trail.

At the end you have put down $M$ edges, so the values on the counters accumulate to $2M$.

The pigeon hole principle gives you one counter with value at least $\frac{2M}n$,
which is the average degree. The trail this counter has travelled is the trail that you are looking for.